# Why does add-on icon disappear, if install.rdf is present?

Tags: firefox-addon

After I’ve install my add-on I don’t see the toolbar icon in Firefox.
I’ve faced this issue during development. If [`install.rdf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests) file is present, the add-on’s icon does not appear in the Firefox toolbar. However, it works absolutely fine without an `install.rdf` file. What is wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
  <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
    <em:id>extensionName@myDomain.com</em:id>
    <em:version>1.23</em:version>
    <em:type>2</em:type>

    <em:targetApplication>
      <Description>
        <em:id>{uuid here}</em:id>
        <em:minVersion>31.*</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>47.*</em:maxVersion>
      </Description>
    </em:targetApplication>

    <em:name>extensionName</em:name>
    <em:description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam voluptates natus soluta quis culpa animi, vitae laborum magnam! Facere reiciendis nihil porro non odio hic deserunt obcaecati soluta, nostrum recusandae!</em:description>
    <em:creator>Name LastName</em:creator>
    <em:homepageURL>http://www.mydDomain.com/</em:homepageURL>
  </Description>
</RDF>
```

Comment: We're going to need more information. A [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be needed to allow us to duplicate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is based on some assumptions regarding your add-on.  It would be quite helpful for you to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE) in the question so we could duplicate the problem. Without an MCVE it is necessary to guess at what your issue really is.

The fact that your extension "works" (or at least shows an icon in the Firefox toolbar) without an `install.rdf` file implies that you are using the add-on SDK. This answer is based on the assumption that you are using the add-on SDK.  If you were not using the add-on SDK, then the add-on should not work at all without an `install.rdf` file and we need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . The add-on SDK automatically generates an `install.rdf` as part of the build process.

I would recommend that take a look at the `install.rdf` that is generated in the build process and duplicate it. You can then make changes to the file should you have things you would like to adjust.

As for the `install.rdf` file you are currently using, at a minimum, you probably need to add:

```
<em:bootstrap>true</em:bootstrap>
```

That would probably be needed as all add-on SDK extensions are restartless. However, the best thing would be to take the automatically generated `install.rdf` and only change the things you need.